# Is there a way to efficiently add multiple key bindings?

Tags: java

I currently am recreating snake and used KeyListener to bind the arrow keys to certain commands. Recently, I heard how Key Bindings are better and decided to make the switch, but barely understood the Oracle article about it.

Right now, to bind the arrow keys, I am having to do this:

```
    panel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0),"left");
    panel.getActionMap().put("left", new AbstractAction(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            addToQueue(LEFT);
        }
    });
    panel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0),"up");
    panel.getActionMap().put("up", new AbstractAction(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            addToQueue(UP);
        }
    });
    // Another two for right and down are in my code but you get the picture.
```

There has to be an easier way to do this, right? I tried googling around but found nothing and I barely know what the InputMap and ActionMap are so I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Comment: Maybe [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) will help with the differences between KeyEvents and Key Bindings. The `MotiionWithKeyBindings.java` example is a complete solution which uses a parameterized Action and a helper method to build the Key Bindings.

Answer (score 1):

While this merely dumps the problem into a function, you could mask this behavior behind a procedure:

```
void bindKeyToAction(Panel p, KeyEvent ke, String id, Object o){

    p.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(ke, 0),id);
    p.getActionMap().put(id, new AbstractAction(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            addToQueue(o);
        }
    });

}
```

Since I don't see an object type of your LEFT and UP objects, I used Object o in the method.

So to bind, you'd just call this function instead.

```
bindKeyToAction(panel, KeyEvent.UP, "up", UP);
bindKeyToAction(panel, KeyEvent.Left, "left", LEFT);
```

Comment: Yea I just dumped the code in a for loop. Also, i think i should have specified that UP, LEFT, RIGHT and DOWN are integer constants.

Comment: I hope we helped, even if just a little! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have a set of `KeyEvent`, `QueueElement` pairs, which can be represented as a map:

```
ImmutableMap<KeyEvent, QueueElement> KEY_BINDINGS = ImmutableMap.of(
  KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, LEFT,
  KeyEvent.VK_UP, UP,
  ...);
```

Then you can register these actions in a loop:

```
for (Entry<KeyEvent, QueueElement> e : KEY_BINDINGS.entrySet()) {
  panel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(e.getKey(), 0),
                          e.getValue().toString());
  panel.getActionMap().put(e.getValue().toString(), new AbstractAction(){
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
          addToQueue(e.getValue());
      }
  });
}
```

This assumes your `QueueElement` type has a meaningful `.toString()`, but if not hopefully that's an easy change - as is you're associating strings like `"up"` with objects like `UP` without any sort of meaning.  Better to make its name a part of the type itself.  You could provide a `.getName()` method or something similar if you can't change `.toString()`.

Comment: I haven't ever used Maps so I just made an Object[] ArrayList to hold the "up", "left"... strings, the UP, LEFT constants (should have specified that they're integer constants in my question), and the KeyStroke.

Comment: Well, that certainly works too.  But maps should be used to maintain relationships (like `VK_LEFT` -> `LEFT`), it'd be a good idea to get up to speed on maps.